# How to assign a domain name to Raspberry WLAN AP?

Tags: networking

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian 1.3 as a WLAN access point. To achieve this, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2002171.htm) (German). Basically I gave it a static IP address of `192.168.1.1` and installed `dnsmasq` and `hostapd`. It is running a node.js app on port 3000 which I can access fine when connected to its WLAN network. Next I'd like to access the app by entering a domain name in the address bar of my browser, instead of `192.168.1.1:3000`. How could this be achieved?
I have tried modifying the following files:

In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` added `domain=mydomain.bla`

In `/etc/hosts` added `192.168.1.1:3000    test.mydomain.bla`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` config file only lists **host-to-IP** address mappings, but **never** (service) **ports**. So, a `:3000` doesn't belong here, simply remove it. You need to specify the port number explicitly in your URL anyway if it differs from port 80. Port numbers in URLs are a dedicated element and don't belong to the host DNS name/IP address part in an URL. They are dealt with within the browser, but not in DNS (DNS SVR RRs are not taken into account when resolving URLs).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and background info, it works now. Would there be any reason not to have the node.js app listen on port 80 so the port doesn't need to be specified in the URL? The sole purpose of the device is to run this app.

Comment: @speedymcs there's no reason against using port 80, unless you already have another webserver running there. But normally, port 80 should be unused.

Comment: No luck though. The app is listening on port 80 now, and in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` I added `domain=test.me` and in `/etc/hosts` I added `192.168.1.1    go.test.me`. But I can't address the server by entering `go.test.me` in the address bar, only the IP address works. Edit: It works when I unplug the ethernet cable, so the browser is obviously searching an internet DNS server instead of the Pi. I guess I'll have to stick to the IP address..?

Comment: `.me` is a TLD, can you check with `.test`?

Comment: I just tried `go.bla.test`. Same behaviour, it works when not connected to the internet, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: Did you restart the dnsmasq service to make sure it picks up the changes? I don't know whether this is necessary or not.

Comment: Yes, I always restart the Pi after changing the settings. And they were picked up, too--the issue is with the client PC which is looking for `go.bla.test` on the internet instead of the LAN it seems. It works fine when ethernet is disabled and the client PC is only connected to the Pi's access point. Entering `go.bla.test` will then take me to its IP on port 80, as desired

Comment: Then I suspect some resolving issue when dnsmasq has an upstream connection, so it probably tries to resolve `.test.` when it shouldn't. You could monitor the DNS traffic using wireshark on `eth0` to find out if that is the case.